# steps to booting up of uboot before reaching start.s

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, u-boot

Suppose I have working uboot & new working board  . I know this board will bring up once I load uboot onto it. My question is what all major steps it will do to reach upto start.s file where all memory initialization,stack ,interrupt etc  will happen .

How does it boots from the flash does it initialize flash drivers first before reaching  to start.s .As per my knowledge it will hit start.s first then all initialization will happen including flash as well.

Comment: Just saying.. Dont be surprised if you get no answers. You're asking the wrong question in the wrong place. Tagging **Flash** makes it seems like you're programming in Adobe Flash, yet this has nothing to do wit it, not even a programming question is it? More about how to setup hardware in Linux(??) using U-Boot(??). I'll edit the tags for you if possible..

Comment: The boot process is highly dependent on the specific architecture, processor and even the board configuration, e.g. where is U-Boot stored?  Your question is essentially unanswerable because a book could be written about all the possible variations.